# How to stitch 3 JPEG files horizontally to generate a big image that represent a 2 pages big crossed words?

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I have scanned a big crossed words (2 pages in a tv magazine) using my personal scanner.

I have now 3 PNG files that I want to combine to generate the original crossed words.

After having scanning LEFT and RIGHT part of crossed words, 4 columns in middle of it are missing.

So I scanned an third image that contains only middle part of crossed words that will contains the 4 missing columns (and more).

All these scans are done manually.

Is there a Windows tools or utility program that generate AUTOMATICALLY (using a script not a GUI program) the original crossed words giving only LEFT, MIDDLE and RIGHT image ?

I have tried to use ImageMagick but I can only juxtapose images not stitching !

Comment: Have you try with phone in panorama mode?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is called
[Image stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching)
or Panorama Stitching.

You may find several free stitchers in the article
[Best Panorama Software for Stitching Images](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/panorama-stitching-best-apps/).

However, it should be a simple matter to use an image editor to cut and fit
together the images, for example using
[Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/).

Comment: thanks for this answer but I search a tool that do the job automatically. I have changed my post to reflect your remark (use 'stitch' verb) and to highlight that I search a script if it is possible because 2 users have decided to close my question !

Comment: My answer was oriented for avoiding closure, but it didn't work.

Comment: I see that and I thank you for your vision of helping others.